# How to detect and find out a program is in deadlock?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, multiprocessing, deadlock

This is an interview question.

How to detect and find out if a program is in deadlock? Are there some tools that can be used to do that on Linux/Unix systems?

My idea:

If a program makes no progress and its status is running, it is deadlock. But, other reasons can also cause this problem. Open source tools are valgrind (halgrind) can do that. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you look at [Helgrind: a thread error detector](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html).

> The simplest example of such a problem is as follows.
>
> Imagine some shared resource R, which, for whatever reason, is guarded by two locks, L1 and L2, which must both be held when R is accessed.
>
> Suppose a thread acquires L1, then L2, and proceeds to access R. The implication of this is that all threads in the program must acquire the two locks in the order first L1 then L2. Not doing so risks deadlock.
>
> The deadlock could happen if two threads -- call them T1 and T2 -- both want to access R. Suppose T1 acquires L1 first, and T2 acquires L2 first. Then T1 tries to acquire L2, and T2 tries to acquire L1, but those locks are both already held. So T1 and T2 become deadlocked."

Answer (score 11):

If you suspect a deadlock, do a `ps aux | grep <exe name>`, if in output, the `PROCESS STATE CODE` is `D` (Uninterruptible sleep) means it is a deadlock. 
Because as @daijo explained, say you have two threads `T1` & `T2` and two critical sections each protected by `semaphores S1 & S2` then if `T1` acquires `S1` and `T2` acquires `S2` and after that they try to acquire the other lock before relinquishing the one already held by them, this will lead to a deadlock and on doing a `ps aux | grep <exe name>`, the `process state code` will be `D` (ie Uninterruptible sleep).

**Tools:**

Valgrind, Lockdep (linux kernel utility)

Check this link on types of deadlocks and how to avoid them : 
http://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2014/01/linux-kernel-deadlocks-and-how-to-avoid.html

**Edit: `ps aux` output `D` "could" mean process is in deadlock, from this [redhat doc](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/processstates_20120831.pdf):**

> **Uninterruptible Sleep State**
>   An Uninterruptible sleep state is one
>   that won't handle a signal right away. It will wake only as a result
>   of a waited-upon resource becoming available or after a time-out
>   occurs during that wait (if the time-out is specified when the process
>   is put to sleep).

Comment: uninterruptible sleep means waiting for any number of resources, typically IO - how can you use that for deadlocks?

Comment: @brokenfoot - I agree with @excalibur, it says in the provided link, that the process `could` be in deadlock.